# Prove that all graphs with Degree Sequence $(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$ have an odd cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I've been asked to prove that a graph with Degree Sequence $(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$ [2-regular, 7 vertices] cannot be bipartite.

I know that bipartite graphs cannot have any cycles of odd length.
I'm fairly certain that the only two graphs that fit the Degree Sequence is either $C_7$ or $C_4$ disconnected from $C_3$.
Both of these contain a cycle of odd length, so they cannot be bipartite.
But I'm not sure how to prove that all graphs with this Degree Sequence must contain a cycle of odd length.

Comment: You're right, one thing you can do to conclude is to show that every connected component of such graph is a cycle, and conclude that you listed all the possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that there is a bipartite graph that has that cycle sequence. Then the $7$ nodes can be partitioned into 2 sets $A,B$ such that the only edges that exist are between a node in $A$ and a node in $B$.

Let's count the number of edges of that graph!

Since each edge has exactly one of it's nodes in $A$, that means there are exactly as many edges as the sum of the degrees of nodes in $A$, that is $2|A|$.

But the same is true for the set $B$, so the number of edges is also $2|B|$. That means $|A|=|B|$, but we also have $|A| + |B| = 7$ ($A$ and $B$ are disjoint and contain together all $7$ nodes).

This is of course impossible, so we have found a contradiction to such a bipartite graph with the given degree sequence existing. The proof only uses that the number of nodes is odd, so easily generalizes to any odd number of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try to make the graph , renaming the Nodes to $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ , & let us **try** to make it Non-Bi-Partite.

Let Node $1$ be in Partition $P1$.
It is connected to Node $2$ & Node $3$ in Partition $P2$.

Let Node $2$ be connected to Node $4$ in Partition $P1$.
Now , [ Case A ] Node $3$ can be connected to Node $4$ (which will make a cycle) or [ Case B ] it can be connected to Node $5$ (which still keeps it open).

In Case A , we are left with Nodes $5,6,7$ , which will have to form a triangle with Cycle length $3$ , which is Non-Bi-Partite.

In Case B , let Node $4$ be connected to Node $6$ in Partition $2$.
Then [ Case B1 ] , Node $5$ is also connected to Node $6$ (which will make a cycle) or [ Case B2 ] it can be connected to Node $7$ (which still keeps it open).

In Case B1 , Node $7$ is left over unconnected , hence Degree is not $2$.
In Case B2 , Node $6$ will have to connect to Node $7$ in Same Partition $P2$ , hence that will not be Bi-Partite.

**Over-all :**
Case A : Non-Bi-Partite
Case B1 : Degree mismatch
Case B2 : Non-Bi-Partite

Hence we can not make it Non-Bi-Partite.

**OBSERVATION :**

Same thing applies to all Degree Sequences with ODD number of $2$ ( Eg $2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2$ )
When we have EVEN Number of $2$ ( Eg $2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2$ ) , we can make it Bi-Partite.
Proof is easy when involving Induction.

Alternate Proof without Induction :
ODD Case : When-ever we make a cycle of $2n+2$ (4 , 6 , 8 , Etc) Nodes , we will be using $2n+2$ Nodes. We will eventually be left with $3$ Nodes (triangle Nodes with Degree $2$) or with $1$ Node (Degree $0$) , hence we can not make it Bi-Partite.
EVEN Case : We can always make a cycle of $2n+2$ (4 , 6 , 8 , Etc) Nodes , such that nothing will be left over , hence we can make it Bi-Partite.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is connected then it is Eulerian and since each vertex has degree 2 it is also Hamiltonian i.e. it is $7$ cycle.

If $G$ has 2 conected components then one has $3$ and the other $4$ vertices and so they are $C_3$ and $C_4$ and we are done.

Clearly $G$ can not have $3$ or more connected components since each has at least $3$ vertices.

So we are done.